# How to inject/Register MediatR ServiceFactory in .Net 6?

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1, mediatr

I have a project that originally written in .Netcore 3.1. I was migrating this project to .Net6.0.

I used to inject/Register the MediatR ServiceFactory with Lifetime: Transient.

```
services.AddTransient<ServiceFactory, ServiceFactory>();
```

But when I migrated to .Net6.0 I've got an error saying:

*`InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.ServiceFactory Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: MediatR.ServiceFactory': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Object' while attempting to activate 'MediatR.ServiceFactory'.`*

I would like to know how can I inject/Register the MediatR ServiceFactory in .Net6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we shouldn't need to register the MediatR service factory as a separate thing. The AddMediatR extension should handle that.